# How to maintain field size for dynamically populated column in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT prop.PropertyId,
   prop.PropertyName,
   ISNULL(finCen.FacilityUse, prop.FacilityUse) AS FacilityUse,
   prop.City,
   prop.State,
FROM Import.Property prop
LEFT JOIN Import.Ims ims
    ON prop.MailCode = ims.PropertyId
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT finCen.Mailcode,
           'Operations Center' AS FacilityUse,
           'OperationsCenter ' AS [Table]
    FROM Import.OperationsCenter finCen
) finCen
    ON finCen.MailId= ims.MaildId
```

and I'm running into a problem on the FacilityUse column. It will only return the first 17 characters of:

```
ISNULL(finCen.FacilityUse, prop.FacilityUse) AS FacilityUse,
```

which corresponds to the number of characters in:

```
'Operations Center' AS FacilityUse,
```

If I expand 'Operations Center' to 'Operations Center ***************' (stars are actually spaces but it wouldn't let me post like that), with the number of spaces allowing for the full FacilityUse field it works.  Not sure how to define the length for that return value

Comment: What's the issue you're having/trying to fix?

Comment: _Column_, not field.

Comment: So there's a facility called 'Standard Operations Facility' but it's only coming back as 'Standard Operatio'.  But if in the subquery I change 'Operations Center' to 'Operations Center<bunch of spaces>', it brings the field back correctly

Comment: Just running the query in SSMS brings back the truncated value

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild that doesn't explain anything *unless* the two fields have different sizes. The size is part of the data type so SQL Server has to decide what type to use for the result of `ISNULL`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I bet this is is the case.   I didn't know this could be an issue, but I bet FacilityUse from Property table is shorter than the phrases he's setting up in is subquery. TrevorGoodchild, look at this link, and adjust accordingly: https://sirsql.net/2015/06/26/isnull-data-length-handling/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`finCen.FacilityUse` is getting defined with a length of 17 characters because that's the length of the hardcoded string value in the inner query.  Try casting the column to force a longer length data type:

```
SELECT prop.PropertyId,
   prop.PropertyName,
   ISNULL(finCen.FacilityUse, prop.FacilityUse) AS FacilityUse,
   prop.City,
   prop.State,
FROM Import.Property prop
LEFT JOIN Import.Ims ims
    ON prop.MailCode = ims.PropertyId
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT finCen.Mailcode,
           CAST('Operations Center' AS VARCHAR(100)) AS FacilityUse,
           CAST('OperationsCenter' AS VARCHAR(100)) AS [Table]
    FROM Import.OperationsCenter finCen
) finCen
    ON finCen.MailId= ims.MaildId;
```

You should cast it to the same datatype as `Import.Property.FacilityUse`